# Unity windows maximisation ghost image

Tags: unity, bug-reporting

I think I have a bug in unity.

Sometimes I move the mouse over the screen without doing something and it seems that Unity want to maximise a ghost window on the left of the screen or on the right.

Look at the screen copy here you'll understand what I mean :

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/440/bugunity.png/]

What is the cause of this - should I file a bug report?

Comment: I have seen the same issue a couple times when I last used Unity on my desktop. My thought is that it is definitely a bug. Whether it has been reported yet I do not know.

Comment: This is a bug - something we cannot help you with. Therefore I'm voting to close this question. A workaround would be to disable the Grid plugin in CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Comment: Yes It's all right now without the grid plugin it's perfect !

Answer (score 2):

I found a bug report of similar problems.

[Bug #886084](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/886084)